# Function works with arm-gcc but not Keil

Tags: c, arrays, compilation, stm32, keil

I am stepping further into embedded development with STM32 and recently started trying to use Keil instead of my hacked together process for using gcc/st-util (since there are fewer steps to get code into device, easy debugging, etc.). Anyway I was moving an early attempt at a function that writes a string to a little 1.8" TFT screen (it was an exercise in Geoffery Brown's book) and it seems that it work if I compile it using gcc but not with Keil. I get the feeling that I must be doing something that doesn't qualify as standard C, or there is an idiosyncrasy I don't know of in the Keil compiler.

I'm sure there is plenty of room for improvement, but my current problem is that `array` never updates, it seems to be an empty array when it goes to write the actual data to the screen. I've tried a few things (using `malloc`, rearranging where it gets updated) but it's always the same, I can see the process get to the line where it sets `color` in the next array value, but that value does not appear in `array`. Any ideas?

Code:

```
void ST7735_WriteString(uint8_t *c, uint16_t size, uint16_t fgColor, uint16_t bgColor)
{
  uint8_t i = 0;
  // How many chars fit across
  uint8_t needAnotherLine = 1;
  uint16_t currentPosition = 0;
  uint8_t currentLine = 0;
  uint16_t boxesLeft = size - currentPosition;
  uint16_t arraySize;

  while (needAnotherLine)
  {
    uint16_t boxesThisRow = 0;
    if (boxesLeft > 25)
    {
      needAnotherLine = 1;
      boxesThisRow = 25;
    }
    else
    {
      needAnotherLine = 0;
      boxesThisRow = boxesLeft;
    }

    // Initialize array which holds the pixel-color data for the row
    arraySize = 66 * boxesThisRow;
    uint16_t array[arraySize];

    // Set new box for line
    ST7735_setAddrWindow(110 - 10 * currentLine, 6, 120 - 10 * currentLine, 6 + 6 * boxesThisRow, 0x6);
    for (i = 0; i < boxesThisRow; i++)
    {
            int8_t k = 0, j = 0;
            uint16_t line;  // font column
            uint8_t bit;    // foreground or background?
            uint16_t color; // which color to draw

            for (k = 0; k < 6; k++)
            {
                line = (k < 5) ? ASCII[5 * (*c++) + k] : 0; // 7-bit bitmap
                for (j = 10; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    // Get bit values
                    bit = (line >> j) & 1;
                    color = bit ? fgColor : bgColor;
                    array[10 - j + k * 11 + i * 66] = color;
                }
            }
    }
    LcdWrite16(LCD_D, array, 66 * boxesThisRow);
    currentPosition += boxesThisRow;
    boxesLeft -= boxesThisRow;
    currentLine++;
  }
}
```

Comment: When you see the problem while debugging, have you checked to see what the array index expression evaluates to, and whether that's within the array bounds?

Comment: For a sufficiently large input string (> 25 characters) I get `arraySize = 0x0672` but array only has one index (0) with value 0x9F0, which I assume is what happens to be in that memory location after the array is initialized. I guess 0x672 could be too large?

Comment: The array isn't initialized at all. It's filled with random values. Do something like `uint16_t array[arraySize] = { 0 };` to initialize it to `0`. And in your while-loop, your array is not getting cleared because you just declare it. So the second time you go through the loop, nothing will happen to the array's existing values. Place the initial declaration outside the loop, and in the loop do `memset(array, 0, arraySize)`